# Date of birth input masking not working on Samsug devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-inputmask

I am using the [inpumask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6oN4.png) plugin

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6oN4.png): https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask for date of birth masking. It has some serious issue of typing on all Samsung series mobile devices. When I type in it just goes on typing in first number of the masked input.

[image]

As its an issue in the plugin so a plugin override solution will highly be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a temporary solution to this DOB format masking issue. I am posting it here so if anyone have that issue they can fix it till the issue is being fixed by the owner.

```
  $.mask.definitions['a'] = '[0123]';
  $.mask.definitions['b'] = '[0-9]';
  $.mask.definitions['c'] = '[01]';
  $.mask.definitions['d'] = '[0-9]';
  $.mask.definitions['e'] = '[12]';
  $.mask.definitions['f'] = '[0-9]';
  $.mask.definitions['g'] = '[0-9]';
  $.mask.definitions['h'] = '[0-9]';
  $(".user-dob").mask("cd/ab/efgh");
```